# Is there a way to plot normal distribution vertically in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi is there a way to plot normal distribution vertically in python matplotlib?
Not Violin plot, Normal distribution at points of the line.

Comment: Yes there will be, but can you give more information about exactly what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.